# как вывести заданную фигуру

Tags: java

Сделал две фигуры но не могу понять как сделать чтобы они подряд выводились

```
public static void main(String []args){
int size=7;
        for(int s=0;s<size;s++){
            for(int k=size-s;k>0;k--){
          System.out.print(" ");    
          }
 
          for(int j=0;j<=s;j++){
          System.out.print(".");    
          }
 
          System.out.println();
      }
      for(int k=0;k<7;k++){
          for(int j=0;j<=k;j++){
          System.out.print(".");    
          }
          System.out.println();
      }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
    int count = 5;

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        for (int j = count - 1; j >= i; j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {

            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

либо так

```
    int count = 5;

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        for (int j = count; j >= 1; j--) {

            if (i >= j) {
                System.out.print("* ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Star Pattern Logic - Part 1 - By Naveen AutomationLabs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2eSm8WIXAw смотри и изучай, у него на канале много интересных фишек...

либо скачай на андройд `java pattern programs free` там под 700 примеров кода для рисования фигур

чтобы разобраться как это работает прогоняй в дебагере пошагово.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, что конкретно должно выводить твоё приложение, просто если соединить то что выводит код из твоего примера, то получится равнобедренная трапеция, у которой верхнее основание состоит из двух точек, а нижнее из 14. А на рисунке показан равнобедренный треугольник. Но в приведённом ниже коде есть и то, и то, и ещё дополнительный пример другого равнобедренного треугольника. Оставляй раскомментированным один из трёх вариантов и выбирай нужный.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 7;
        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < size; iteration++) {
            for (int space = size - iteration; space > 0; space--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            //case 1
            for (int dot = 0; dot < 2 * iteration + 2; dot++) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            //case2
//            for (int dot = 0; dot < 2 * iteration + 1; dot++) {
//                System.out.print(".");
//            }
            //case 3
//            for (int dot = 0; dot < iteration + 1; dot++) {
//                System.out.print(". ");
//            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```